# What is scholarship score in paper review?

Tags: peer-review

I got paper reviews and I found there is an item **scholarship**,

[image]

Can anyone tell what is scholarship score mean in paper review?

Comment: Ask the editor, that seems to be a scale decided by that particular house or reviewer.

Comment: A lot of journals, conferences, publishers, universities, etc, provide guidelines on how to review a paper, and much of this is online. But without knowing who precisely the review is for it's hard to comment. The following guidelines identify scholarship with citing sources but it's hard to know if that applies in your case: https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/u.endriss/teaching/comsoc/2011/how-to-write-a-review.txt

Comment: @SolarMike Thank you, I will check the FAQ.

Comment: @StuartF Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

A guess but robably means good use of the pre-existing literature.

Answer (score -2):

From the [dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/scholarship),

> *noun*
>
> 1. learning; knowledge acquired by study; the academic attainments of a scholar.
> 2. a sum of money or other aid granted to a student, because of merit, need, etc., to 
>      pursue his or her studies.
> 3. the position or status of such a student.
> 4. a foundation to provide financial assistance to students.

This is the first meaning - it's a measure of how much knowledge your paper adds to the world.

Comment: How is that different from significance and originality?

Comment: I would understand it as "level of academic professionalism" - i.e. quality of literature review, development, solidity of analysis and similar, as compared to, say, "technical quality" which probably would refer to no errors in derivation, etc. I would see them as related, though.